# AngularJS: Re-randomize ng-repeat on each ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm acquainting myself with AngularJS and putting together a simple random-draw app. I have four buttons, allowing you to "draw" either one or two cards from either of two decks (represented by two separate JSON files). As built, my sample app *mostly* works - but the randomization doesn't occur if clicking a button for the deck currently being shown (you get the same exact data in the same exact order)... it only re-randomizes if you click to draw from the *other* deck, and then back again.

I'm still befuddled by some of Angular's "magic", and I can see that the filter *is* being triggered on each click... so I'm left scratching my head on this one.

Here's the HTML...

```
<div ng-controller="Cards">

    <p>
        <button ng-click="whichDeck=franchises;qty=1;shuffle=undefined">DRAW FRANCHISE</button><button ng-click="whichDeck=franchises;qty=2">X2</button>
    </p>

    <p>
        <button ng-click="whichDeck=twists;qty=1">DRAW TWIST</button><button ng-click="whichDeck=twists;qty=2">X2</button>
    </p>

    <ul class="cards">
        <li class="card" ng-repeat="card in whichDeck | shuffle | limitTo:qty"> <!-- filter:query -->
            <h2>{{card.Title}}</h2>
            <h3 ng-show="card.Origin">{{card.Origin}}</h3>
            <p>{{card.Description}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the JS...

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['Shuffle']);

app.controller('Cards', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    var controller = this;

    $scope.franchises = [];
    $scope.twists = [];
    $scope.deck = '';

    $http.get('js/franchises.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.franchises = data;
    });
    $http.get('js/twists.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.twists = data;
    });

}]);

var shuffle = angular.module('Shuffle', []);

shuffle.filter('shuffle', function() {    
    var shuffledArr = [],
        shuffledLength = 0;
    return function(arr) {
        if (typeof(arr)==='undefined')
            arr = [];
        var o = arr.slice(0, arr.length);
        if (shuffledLength == arr.length) return shuffledArr;
        for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        shuffledArr = o;
        shuffledLength = o.length;
        return o;
    };
});
```

Comment: Two things... first, it turns out that the shuffle filter I was using (from another StackOverflow thread) is designed to NOT refresh. The reason for this is that Angular will throw digest errors like crazy when you do this sort of complex operation in a filter (filters run a LOT and therefore have limits). Second: By pulling the shuffle out of a filter and putting it in the controller, you avoid the digest error problem and get the fresh shuffle on every click. Thanks, Mosho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how this can be achieved, I think you are way over-complicating things.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="Ctrl"> 
    <button ng-click="shuffle(obj)">shuffle</button>
   <div ng-repeat="o in obj">
       {{o}}
    </div>   
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.obj = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    //generic shuffling function
    $scope.shuffle = function(o){ 
        for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o;
    };
};
```

`ng-repeat` uses the order of the array, and changes to the array in the scope will be reflected in the view automagically.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BN3DM/)